# Color spectrum of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector

```
vector_v = [-10, ... -0.001, 0, 0.001, ..., 10]
```

I want to use its values as colors in ggplot. I want all 
points above and below zero to have different colors.

I tried

```
mid <- mean(mtcars$qsec) 
sp2 + scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mid, low="blue", mid="white", high="red", space ="Lab" )
```

from [STHDA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually)

But the color changes gradually about zero. I want the color change to be sharp so the small numbers around zero like -0.001 and 0.001 are distinguishable.

Any idea?

If it helps, the code for `sp2` part is:

```
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = states_cluster, 
             aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey", 
                 color = "black") +
geom_point(aes_string(x = "long", y = "lat",
           color = vector_v), alpha = 0.4, size=.4)
```

Comment: You should probably include your code for `sp2` in your question...

Comment: scale_colour_gradient2

Comment: Please also add `dput(head(states_cluster))` output.